# Javascript display area toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

Without using jQuery, i want to display a div (single) on open, then click on an image (plus) link to close "single" and open another div (multi). At the same time the image "plus" is to change (to minus). Clicking on the "minus" image will then close the "multi" div, open the "single" div and change the image to "plus".

I have found an example on the web that has got me half way there but i can't seem to figure out how to hide "multi" on open and then hide "single" on the image click. The "single" div toggles ok but i can't seem to integrate the "multi" into my code. I ether get the image showing up in the div where its not meant to be, or the "multi" div won't toggle.

```
<style type="text/css">
#headerDivImg, #contentDivImg, #contentDivImg_, #contentDivImg1, #contentDivImg1_ {
    float: left;
    width: 510px;
    background-color: #FFE694;
    text-align: center;
}
#titleTextImg {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
}
#imageDivLink {
    float: right;
}
#headerDivImg {
    background-color: #0037DB;
    color: #9EB6FF;
}
#contentDivImg, #contentDivImg_, contentDivImg1, #contentDivImg1_ {
    background-color: #FFE694;
    text-align: center;
}
#headerDivImg img {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle5(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {
    var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
    var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="images/minus.png">';
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="images/plus.png">';
    }
}
</script>

<div id="headerDivImg">
    <div id="titleTextImg">Click to toggle</div>
    <a id="imageDivLink" href="javascript:toggle5('contentDivImg', 'contentDivImg1', 'imageDivLink');"><img src="images/plus.png"></a>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="contentDivImg" style="display: block;">single</div>
<br />
<div id="contentDivImg1" style="display: block;">multi</div>
```

Comment: Copy in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xB4Cx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a lot of changes if your code which you can see in [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/xB4Cx/2/).

HTML:

```
<div id="headerDivImg">
    <div id="titleTextImg">Click to toggle</div>
    <a id="imageDivLink" href="#">
        <img />
    </a>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="contentDivImg">single</div>
<br />
<div id="contentDivImg1">multi</div>
```

JS:

```
//Toggle button
var btnToggle = document.getElementById('imageDivLink');

//Container one
var divSingle = document.getElementById('contentDivImg');

//Container two
var divMultip = document.getElementById('contentDivImg1');

// Toggle button click event handler.
btnToggle.onclick = function(e){
    //Check if open single
    var showSingle =  btnToggle.classList.contains('open');
    if (showSingle){
        divSingle.classList.add('open');
        btnToggle.classList.remove('open');
        divMultip.classList.remove('open');
    }else{
        divSingle.classList.remove('open');
        btnToggle.classList.add('open');
        divMultip.classList.add('open');
    }
};
```

CSS:

```
#headerDivImg, #contentDivImg, #contentDivImg_, #contentDivImg1, #contentDivImg1_ {
    float: left;
    width: 510px;
    background-color: #FFE694;
    text-align: center;
}
#titleTextImg {
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 5px;
}
#imageDivLink {
    float: right;
}
#headerDivImg {
    background-color: #0037DB;
    color: #9EB6FF;
}
#contentDivImg, #contentDivImg_, contentDivImg1, #contentDivImg1_ {
    background-color: #FFE694;
    text-align: center;
}

#contentDivImg {    display: none;}
#contentDivImg.open {    display: block;}

#contentDivImg1 {    display: none;}
#contentDivImg1.open {    display: block;}

#imageDivLink img {
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
    content:url("http://blendme.in/psds/brankic1979/plus%20transparent%20.png"); 
}

#imageDivLink.open img {
    content:url("http://blendme.in/psds/brankic1979/minus%20transparent.png"); 
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xB4Cx/2/)

Comment: Works very well - I'm not going meant to say thanks here but I will anyway.  Thank you!

Comment: Then check my answer as correct and instead of saying 'Thank you!' voteup my answer

Comment: Can't upvote yet as I haven't been on the site long enough but just discovered the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
        var key = 0;
        function toggle() {
            if (key == 0) {
                document.getElementById('imageDivLink').innerHTML = "<img src="images/minus.png">";
                document.getElementById("contentDivImg").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("contentDivImg1").style.display = "block";
                key = 1;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('imageDivLink').innerHTML = "<img src="images/plus.png">";
                document.getElementById("contentDivImg").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("contentDivImg1").style.display = "none";
                key = 0;
            }
        }
<div id="headerDivImg">
<div id="titleTextImg">Click to toggle</div>
<a id="imageDivLink" href="javascript:toggle();"><img src="images/plus.png"></a>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div id="contentDivImg" style="display: block;">single</div>
<br />
<div id="contentDivImg1" style="display: none;">multi</div>
```